# Opera 20 - bookmark importer option greyed out?

Tags: browser, bookmarks, opera, import

Does anyone know how to enable Opera 20's bookmark importer? It's in the main Opera dropdown, but it's greyed out. I have already enabled the bookmarks bar in Opera > Settings.

Comment: I assume you are using the stand-alone version of Opera where this usually happens. I don't know how to enable the bookmarks importer, but I do know a [workaround to import old bookmarks.](http://superuser.com/a/726383/50173).